# Onsubmit event opens new window

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the below form class that has onsubmit event opens a new window?
When ever I click on the submit button of the form class, I dont want new window to open. Please suggest an idea.I tried replacing obsubmit with action however in chrome it works fine where as in Internet Explorer it opens a new window

```
<form class="  " onsubmit="javascript:MyFunction()" target="_blank" role="search">     
 </form>
```

Comment: Maybe `target="_blank"`?

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes. They're always Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are using `target ="blank"` take out that line and it should keep you in the same window.

Comment: `"out that line"`. take out that *attribute*, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `target="_blank"` attribute.